# Identificar se o computador possui leitor de QR Code

Tags: javascript, html5, qrcode, webcam

A primeira etapa de cadastro do meu projeto tem duas opções de layout: uma para quem possui leitor de QR Code (web cam) e outra para quem não tem.

Preciso identificar se o browser do usuário possui acesso à webcam para leitura do QR Code, como posso fazer essa verificação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar HTML5 para detectar se o usuário possui ou não um dispositivo de gravação de vídeo disponível:

```js
navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                      navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                      navigator.msGetUserMedia);

navigator.getMedia({video: true}, function() {
  //Câmera disponível
  $('.com-leitor').show();
  $('.sem-leitor').hide();
}, function() {
  //Câmera não disponível
  $('.com-leitor').hide();
  $('.sem-leitor').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='com-leitor'>SUCCESS! =)</div>

<div class='sem-leitor'>FAIL! =(</div>
```

[Fonte.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23289012/1845714)

Comment: Um ele ate identificou a cam, mas na hora de mostrar o conteudo ele não funcionou. Coloquei   `$('.com-leitor').hide();` e `$('.sem-leitor').hide();`  ai no meio do código que vc postou coloquei um   `$('.com-leitor').show();`
 e `$('.sem-leitor').show();`   ...

Comment: @Erick Modifiquei a resposta para incluir um teste funcional.

Comment: Legal entendi a lógica estou mexendo aqui, n esta dando certo por enquanto mas talvez eu esteja errando. Meu sistema é o seguinte: Usuario entra na home e tem duas opções Login ou Cadastro se clicar no cadastro essa primeira div com os campos de login e botao de cadastro some e entra outra com o proximo passo e nessa hora o sistema verificar se tem webcam ou não.  Vou tentar outras opções em vez de hide() e show().  vlw

Comment: @Erick sem estresse - em caso de qualquer outra dúvida, sinta-se à vontade para criar outra pergunta!

Comment: Aparentemente funcionou com removeClass.  Testei no chrome uma vez com a camera habilitada e outra com ela bloqueada  e funcionou, vou testar em outros navegadores.  obrigado.